# Pointwise or Uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Consider the functions $f_n:[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$$f_n(x):= \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + \tfrac 1n}}$$ and determine whether the convergence is uniform or pointwise.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

> If a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converges pointwise to a
>   function $f$ and uniformly to a function $g$, then $f=g$.

and

> If a sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converges uniformly to a
>   function $f$, then $f$ is continuous.

- Prove convergence pointwise to the function $f\colon[-1,1]\mapsto \operatorname{sign}(x)$ as you started: fix $x_0\in[-1,1]$ arbitrarily, and consider the  limit of the sequence of real numbers $(f_n(x_0))_{n\geq 1}$. (You may want to consider separately the case $x_0<0$, $x_0=0$ and $x_0>0$.)
- Then, for uniform convergence... see how to apply the two statements above.

Comment: A trick to avoid one distinction of case (but that's really not necessary, and the "optimization of time" is marginal): all the $f_n$'s is odd, so you can restrict yourself to the study on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Fix for instance $x_0 \in(0,1]$. Then
$$
\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{n}}} = \frac{x}{\lvert x\rvert}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{nx_0}}} = 1\cdot  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{nx_0}}}.
$$
Since $nx_0 \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty$, the RHS converges to $1$. You do not need $\varepsilon-\delta$-proofs here: if you have a continuous function  $\phi$ and a sequence $a_n\to \ell$, then $\phi(a_n) \to \phi(\ell)$.

Comment: Sorry, in the comment above the $x$'s should be $x_0$'s. (Typing $\LaTeX$ in comments is a bit painful.)

Comment: Fix $\varepsilon> 0$. We can write $$
\left\lvert \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{nx_0}}} - 1\right\rvert
= 
\left\lvert \frac{1-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{nx_0}}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{nx_0}}}\right\rvert
= 
\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{nx_0}}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{nx_0}}}
\leq \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{nx_0}}-1
$$
Having the RHS less than $\varepsilon$ is equivalent to having 
$$
\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{nx_0}} \leq 1+\varepsilon
$$
which, reorganizing and massaging a bit, is equivalent to having
$$
\frac{1}{n} \leq x_0\left( (1+\varepsilon)^2-1 \right).
$$

Comment: So picking $N = \left\lceil \frac{1}{x_0\left( (1+\varepsilon)^2-1 \right)} \right\rceil$ ensures that, for $n\geq N$, the RHS is less than $\varepsilon.$ (Having checked carefully the derivation, but that's the gist of it.)

Comment: It is $x_0$, I believe. Try to go through the derivation step by step?